# Sending data from javascript to controller after view has rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a controller that has a GET parameter. My Javascript grabs the GET parameter and uses it to grab data from an API. The issue im having is im not sure how to set up my controller side functions/actionresults to accept ajax data and modify the viewmodel. Do i need a seperate function or just modify the HTML from the client-side.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string locationinput)
        { 
             //ViewModel data processing...
             return View();
        }
```

Search View:

```
         @model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel>

         <div class="container">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.formatted_address)     
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.zip)
                    }
         </div>
```

Comment: This view belongs to Search action and you want to make request from js?

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 Yes.

Comment: when you get data from server with ajax you cant use it with razor

Comment: So my only option is to modify the HTML from JS?

Comment: you can return partialview from server and insert in view with js

Answer (score 0):

```
public PartialViewResult Search(string locationinput)
        {
            List<SearchResultsViewModel> srvm=getSomething(locationinput);

            return PartialView(srvm);
        }
```

Search view

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel>

         <div class="container">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.formatted_address)     
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.zip)
                    }
         </div>
```

and js

```
$('#btnAjax').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/Search',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'

        })
        .success(function (result) {
            $('#searchresults').html(result);
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        })
    });
```